# If statement does not read char variable properly

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

When calling the programs starLeftTriangle & starRightTriangle, the *if statements* seem to ignore the variable *choice* and the program continuously runs as if the choice is 'l' or 'L'.

Any idea why the if statements are being ignored? I've omitted the actual code for the programs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void starLeftTriangle(int n);
void starRightTriangle(int n);


int main() {
int star;
char choice;
cout << "Input the number of stars you want to draw: \n";
cin >> star;
cout << "Would you like to draw a left triangle, right triangle, or quit?     \n";
cin >> choice;

cout << "The choice value is " << choice << endl;

system("pause");

while (choice != 'q' || 'Q'){
    if (choice == 'l' || 'L'){
        starLeftTriangle(star);
    }
    else if (choice == 'r' || 'R') {
        starRightTriangle(star);
    }
}
if (choice == 'q' || 'Q') {
    cout << "Quitting Program.";

}
else{
//throw error
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `choice != 'q' || 'Q'` doesn't do what you think it does. It means either `choice` is not `'q'`, or `'Q'` is true, and the latter is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to express an equality/inequality for *each* term in your `while` and `if` conditions:

```
while (choice != 'q' && choice != 'Q') {
    if (choice == 'l' || choice == 'L') {
         starLeftTriangle(star);
    }
    else if (choice == 'r' || choice == 'R') {
        starRightTriangle(star);
    }
}
if (choice == 'q' || choice == 'Q') {
    cout << "Quitting Program.";
}
else {
    // throw error
}
```

What I think is currently happening is that for some value of `choice` the following `if` condition is always coming up true:

```
if (choice == 'l' || 'L') {
     starLeftTriangle(star);
}
```

The reason for this is if `choice` in fact be `'l'` then this will be true, but if not, your other condition is `'L'`, which will also evaluate to true.  To avoid this, use equalities everywhere.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks for the edit ;-)

Comment: You're the man. Thank you.

Comment: I think what he wants in the first condition is `(choice != 'q' && choice != 'Q')` though. The condition `(choice != 'q' || choice != 'Q')` would always be true and result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @user1488118 Very nice catch.  The logic rule here is: `!(p V q) == (!p ^ !q)`

Comment: @user1488118 I'm not sure if I'm missing something. As long as choice is not q or Q, then I want the inner to run. I don't see why you would need an and.

Comment: Because you want it to be true when the character is NOT q AND NOT Q. In other words if it's something else than Q/q. The way it was originally proposed in the answer would mean it's true when it's NOT q OR NOT Q. However, one of these two conditions is always true since the character can never have both values at the same time. Consequently, the expression would always evaluate to true because always one of the operands would be true.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is being interpreted as follows: `choice == 'q'` OR `'Q'` - integer code of Q is more than 0, so it will always return `true` for any character in compraison
Try this one:

```
bool loop = true;
while (loop) {
  switch ((int) choice) {
    case (int) 'l':
    case (int) 'L':
      starLeftTriangle(star);
      break;
    case (int) 'r':
    case (int) 'R':
      starRightTriangle(star);
      break;
    case (int) 'q':
    case (int) 'Q':
      loop=false;
      break;
  }
}
```